# google maps api suddenly stopped working

Tags: php, google-maps

There is wierd situation ... everything was working and suddenly googlemaps api stopped working

```
$('input#find_location_button').on('click', function () {

.... some script to get value of input field and store it in data_to_send.... 
data_to_send['sensor'] = 'false';

   //   alert(JSON.stringify(data_to_send));  this alert shows everything is fine

        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: data_to_send,
            type: 'GET',
            success: function (data)
            { alert(data); // nothing ... 
.... proper closing tags ...
```

I have no idea why this ajax request suddenly stopped working ... in firbug console it shows nothing ... no request posted ... any ideas?

Comment: There's no way this was working before. It violates cross-domain policy. Try changing the `dataType` parameter to `jsonp` instead of `json`

Comment: yes it was working, local AND online .... btw, and i changed the datatype to jsonp .. its still dead ...

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this issue [missing CORS HTTP Header](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4921) explains why it stopped working.

Google Geocoding Web Service is not including Access-Control-Allow-Origin:* in HTTP header responses, so service cannot be cross-domain accesed from javascript.
Until last week Friday, that header was included.

Start that issue if that is the problem.