# Gmaps HTTP request fails through JS but get result on browser

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I've been struggling for a bit of time on this weird issue.

I am basically running the following GET request: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?key=AIzaSyAqrDaQOszbVjKgK9YJQzfkVOXFEOLJH1Y&placeid=ChIJYWzsQuNRqEcRTmcQwwzoPGw

Works fine if I run on my browser directly or on Postman.
Fails when running with javascript or Jquery. See fiddle here:
https://jsfiddle.net/luron01/4L86x30c/2/

```
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
            xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
xmlhttp.open("GET", 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?key=AIzaSyAqrDaQOszbVjKgK9YJQzfkVOXFEOLJH1Y&placeid=ChIJYWzsQuNRqEcRTmcQwwzoPGw', true );
    xmlhttp.send();

  console.log(xmlhttp.responseText)
```

I believe I have all necessary APIs enabled (Google Places API Web,Service (Private API), Google Maps JavaScript API,Google Maps Geolocation API).

Any hint would be really great!
Thanks

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: Possibly related question: [Getting JSON of Google Places Nearby Search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34028977/getting-json-of-google-places-nearby-search)

Comment: Possibly related question: [google maps api suddenly stopped working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14882282/google-maps-api-suddenly-stopped-working)

Comment: I get an empty result and the Xmlhttp.satus=0.